# Extract text data from website using Python:

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract text data from website using regex but problem is it is not completely extracting. I am following this tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/parse-website-using-regular-expressions-urllib 
but i dont know where i am wrong. The website i am extracting text from is http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-1/ and its relevant sublinks as well.

Code:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request
import re
#url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_basic_syntax.htm"
url = "http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-1/"

req = Request(url)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

regex = '<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p>'

paragraphs = re.findall(regex,str(respData))


for eachP in paragraphs:
    print(eachP)
```

any idea ???

Comment: try to use a package such as `BeautifulSoup` instead of using regex.

Comment: you are not using `regex` variable, which is more correct

Comment: If you're not too attached to regex, you could try BeautifulSoup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: can u suggest how to use Beautifulsoup to exract text from website that contains question and answer?

Comment: Make it a multi-line match and include newlines in the `.` metacharacter:  `paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',str(respData), flags=re.M|re.S)`

Comment: http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html

Comment: the output is very longer and it is als giving "div, html, <p>.... "and so many tags which i dont need. i just need question and answers portion. Any idea what shd i do?

Comment: @stribizhev sorry can u improve ur answer bcz i am confused whether shell i add ur suggestion to my code or i shd re-write. I am already reading the docs and example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `BeautifulSoup` for this. This is easy and better than regex.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print p.get_text().encode('utf-8') + "\n\n"
```

The `utf-8` is used as you have unicode text on your source url.

Here you'll find how to install [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup).

Comment: shell i add after "paragraphs = re.findall(regex,str(respData),flags=re.M|re.S)" ??

Comment: or replace with paragraphs = re.findall(regex,str(respData),flags=re.M|re.S) ?

Comment: 1 thing more i am not getting "View answer" tage from website: "http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-1/" can u suggest reason?

Comment: That is under different tag. If you go through the documentation in detail, you'll learn it more.

Comment: web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/  
that one?

Comment: so it has unique class which is "collapseomatic_content" and i tried to place  BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'html.parser','collapseomatic_content') but gave ne error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_xml'"

Answer (score 0):

I found a good one for extracting paragraphs from [How to Scrape Paragraphs using Python?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-scrape-paragraphs-using-python/)

**With example:**

```
# import module
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
# Html doc
html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
<title>Geeks</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>paragraphs</h2>
  
<p>Welcome geeks.</p>
  
  
<p>Hello geeks.</p>
  
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
  
# traverse paragraphs from soup
for data in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(data.get_text())
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome geeks.
Hello geeks.
```

**Extract Paragraphs from the given URL:**

```
# import module
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
# link for extract html data
def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
  
htmldata = getdata("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
data = ''
for data in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(data.get_text())
```

**Output:**

[image: Output Image]

**Multiple Urls:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


Newlines = re.compile(r'[\r\n]\s+')

def getPageText(url):
    # given a url, get page content
    data = urlopen(url).read()
    # parse as html structured document
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    # kill javascript content
    for s in soup(["script", "style"]):
        s.replaceWith('')
    # find body and extract text
    for p in soup.find_all('p'):
        txt = print(p.get_text())
    # remove multiple linebreaks and whitespace
    return Newlines.sub('\n', txt)

def main():
    urls = [
        'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-download-install-nltk-on-windows/',
        'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-scrape-paragraphs-using-python/'
    ]
    txt = [getPageText(url) for url in urls]
    for t in txt:
        print(t)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
NLTK is Natural Language Tool Kit. It is used to build python programming. It helps to work with human languages data. It gives a very easy user interface. It supports classification, steaming, tagging, etc.Installing NLTK on Windows using PIP:In windows, we first have to install the python current version. Then we have to install pip with it. Without pip, NLTK can not be installed.Step 1: Browse to the official site of python by clicking this link.Step 2: Move the cursor to the Download button & then click on the latest python version.Step 3: Open the downloaded file. Click on the checkbox & Click on Customize installation.Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
In windows, we first have to install the python current version. Then we have to install pip with it. Without pip, NLTK can not be installed.Step 1: Browse to the official site of python by clicking this link.Step 2: Move the cursor to the Download button & then click on the latest python version.Step 3: Open the downloaded file. Click on the checkbox & Click on Customize installation.Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 1: Browse to the official site of python by clicking this link.Step 2: Move the cursor to the Download button & then click on the latest python version.Step 3: Open the downloaded file. Click on the checkbox & Click on Customize installation.Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 2: Move the cursor to the Download button & then click on the latest python version.Step 3: Open the downloaded file. Click on the checkbox & Click on Customize installation.Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 2: Move the cursor to the Download button & then click on the latest python version.Step 3: Open the downloaded file. Click on the checkbox & Click on Customize installation.Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 3: Open the downloaded file. Click on the checkbox & Click on Customize installation.Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 3: Open the downloaded file. Click on the checkbox & Click on Customize installation.Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 4: Click on Next.Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 5: Click on Install.Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 6: Wait till installation finish.Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 7: Click on Close.Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 8: Open Command Prompt & execute the following commands:python --version
pip --version
pip install nltkHence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Hence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Hence, NLTK installation will start.Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Step 9: Then you can see the successfully installed message.Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Hence NLTK installation is successfulMy Personal Notes
arrow_drop_upSave
Writing code in comment?
Please use ide.geeksforgeeks.org,
generate link and share the link here.
```